# cannot execute snap.py code for CNM community detection

Tags: python, graph

Hy everyone, I'm new to `snap.py`.

I tried to execute the following **code** which I downloaded [from here](http://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/doc/reference/CommunityCNM.html)

Using the **dataset** which can be [downloaded here.](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/ca-GrQc.html)

```
import snap
UGraph = snap.LoadEdgeList(snap.PUNGraph, "CA-GrQc.txt")
# UGraph = snap.GenRndGnm(snap.PUNGraph, 100, 1000)
CmtyV = snap.TCnComV()
modularity = snap.CommunityCNM(UGraph, CmtyV)
for Cmty in CmtyV:
    print "Community: "
    for NI in Cmty:
        print NI
print "The modularity of the network is %f" % modularity
```

When I execute it I get the following **runtime error**:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Ahmed/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/snap_CNM.py", line 
> 44, in <module>
>     modularity = snap.CommunityCNM(g, CmtyV)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\snap.py", line 31114, in CommunityCNM
>     return _snap.CommunityCNM(Graph, CmtyV)
> RuntimeError: Execution stopped: (0<=ValN)&&(ValN<Vals) [Reason:'Index:-1 
> Vals:5242 MxVals:5242 Type:TVec<class THashKeyDat<class TInt,struct 
> TSnap::TSnapDetail::TCNMQMatrix::TCmtyDat>,int>'], file s:\glib-core\ds.h, 
> line 491
> ```

but when I execute the code after *commenting the second line and uncommenting the third* line, it is **working properly**.

I've relabeled the nodes in the dataset to make them start from 0 to 5241 and I get the same error.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here and how to fix the error?